# Proper way to handle auto generated inline buttons in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I need to generate a custom inline menu where buttons are autogenerated from my database with a callback based on ID:

```py
class ItemButton:
    def __init__(self, id=None):
        self.id = id


buttons = [
    [InlineKeyboardButton("➕ New item", callback_data="new_item")]
]
for item in items:
    buttons.append(
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            item.name,
            callback_data=ItemButton(id=item.id))
        ],
    )
```

To handle pressing these buttons I try to use:

```
dispatcher.add_handler(
    CallbackQueryHandler(item_edit, pattern=ItemButton)
)
```

But got an error:

`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Maybe I try to do that task entirely the wrong way?
What is the proper way to handle auto-generated buttons in python-telegram-bot?

Comment: can you please show the full traceback of the exception? If you have an error handler activated that hides the traceback, please deactivate it.

Comment: @CallMeStag :
`File "...virtualenvs/epical/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 548, in process_update
    check = handler.check_update(update)
  File "...virtualenvs/epical/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/callbackqueryhandler.py", line 198, in check_update
    match = re.match(self.pattern, callback_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 191, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Thanks. I can't reproduce the issue on the lastest version of PTB. which version are you on? please show the output of `python -m telegram`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve a problem with class but found a working solution. I'm considering not to use the class for matching but use string instead:

`callback_data='articles_42'`

And pattern:

`CallbackQueryHandler(item_edit, pattern='^articles_[0-9]+$')`

And parse this callback data in my callback:

```py
def item_edit(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    item_id = update.callback_query.data.split('_')[-1]
```